# Mint 20 cinnamon - Hot corner open root terminal

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, root, cinnamon

I'm using **Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon** and I'd like to configure my hot corners so that when the mouse passes over a corner, a **terminal is displayed as root**.
I managed to do this in a previous version but I don't remember which command I entered.
If anyone has an idea? thank you very much in advance.

Comment: did you try to search in Google? I dont use Mint 20 CInnamon but Mint 20 Mate and I don't have it - but I saw this somewhere long time ago and it should be in some settings. Digging in Google I fould that it has to be somewhere in Compiz settings. [Mint 17 MATE and hot corners](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/2k0cin/mint_17_mate_and_hot_corners/)

Comment: of course I searched a little bit everywhere . it works well with a command but not at all with compiz.
in my mint 19.x version it was ok but I upgraded without saving my configuration and I don't remember the exact command...